# Visual SVN Server - service start logon failure due to disabled account

Tags: windows, svn, windows-services, visualsvn-server

I'm working with Visual SVN Server. For some reason the service was stopped. When I tried to restart it, it failed due to logon error.

I found, that the guy who set it up earlier has left the organization and his account on the server is disabled. SVN Server is using his account credentials to start the service and failing.

I need to change the authentication credentials, but not able to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean that the guy who left set VisualSVN Server service to run under HIS user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the TechNet article ["Configure How a Service Is Started"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx) for the detailed instruction:

1. **Start**, click in the **Start Search** box, type `services.msc` , and then press **ENTER**,
2. In the details pane, right-click the VisualSVN Server service, and then click **Properties**,
3. To specify the user account that the service can use to log on, click the **Log On** tab, and there you can specify the account.

VisualSVN Server works under the `NETWORK SERVICE` by default however you can also run it under a dedicated account.

You may also want to check these articles if you will create a new service account:

- ["Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/),
- ["Configuring VisualSVN Server service to run under a dedicated user account"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/).